# Google api that convert voice to text?

Tags: java, android, google-api, desktop-application

I know that Android has function to convert voice into text. Also I have seen that google has this functionality, too. In fact, google has introduced this in Android .
I want to use google Voice to Text api in my desktop application. So is there any google api that is for desktop application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is: https://github.com/gillesdemey/google-speech-v2/

You need to enable this API in google programmer console, to do that you need to add your self to chromium devel list, because in other case this option is hiddden. Then you need to acquire the API key.

To encode files to desired flac format for sending them to google server, you can use: http://javaflacencoder.sourceforge.net/

Comment: it have worked for me, about a month ago. As far i know google didn't change their API, because there are people who are paying to use it.